# JSON data returned by API not showing in webdatarocks angular

Tags: angular, webdatarocks

I am trying to display the data returned by REST api in json format using angular but nothing loads on screen. Any idea how to achieve that?

Below is what I am trying to do -

```
getData() {
   this.service.getData().subscribe((res) => {
     this.result = res;


this.pivotReport = 
         {
     
            "dataSource": {
               "dataSourceType":"json",
               "data":this.result
             },
            "slice": {
                "rows": [
                  {
                     "uniqueName":"Country",
                     "sort":"asc"
                  },
                  {
                     "uniqueName":"Business Type",
                     "sort":"asc"
                  },
                  {
                     "uniqueName":"Category"
                  }
                 ],
                "columns": [
                     // {
                     //    "uniqueName":"Category",
                     //    "sort":"asc"
                     // },
                     // {
                     //    "uniqueName":"Country",
                     //    "sort":"asc"
                     // }
                 ]
}
});
}
```

Comment: more context please, could you share a stackblitz with your example ?

Comment: the data is not enough to help you... you need to share some of your component and related view code.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing loads on the screen because you need to pass the report into the pivot component explicitly.
You should use the `setReport()` command to do that.
Find examples of this method in [documentation](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/setreport/).

Also, your report example seems to display an empty grid even if all data is passed to pivot.
You may also try to set `measures` to aggregate your data, like this:

```
"slice": {
      "rows": [...],
      "columns": [...],
      "measures": [{
       "uniqueName": "Category",
       "aggregation": "count"
      }]
    }
```